# how to remove the shadow for the label added to pie plot using core plot libraru in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-plot

I had added shadow for pie plot but I'm getting shadow for the label data also. I want to remove that shadow. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
            piePlot.dataSource = self;
    piePlot.pieRadius = 65.0;
    piePlot.pieInnerRadius = 35.0;  
    piePlot.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    piePlot.shadowRadius = 3.0;
    piePlot.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8,-3);
    piePlot.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    piePlot.identifier = @"Current Year Credits By Type";
    piePlot.startAngle = M_PI_4;
    piePlot.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
    piePlot.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    piePlot.sliceLabelOffset = 10.0;
```

-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

```
CPTTextLayer *newLayer = nil;

static CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteText = nil;

if ( !whiteText )
{
    whiteText = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    whiteText.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
}

if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPTPieChart class]] ) 
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pieChartData1 objectAtIndex:index]];

    newLayer = [[[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:str style:whiteText] autorelease];

}

return newLayer;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Core Plot's `CPTShadow` class instead of the `CALayer` shadow properties.

```
CPTMutableShadow *blackShadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
blackShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8,-3);
blackShadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor blackColor];

piePlot.shadow = blackShadow;
```

Comment: It is showing errors as (1) 'CPTMutableShadow' undeclared(first use in this function).(2)'blackShadow' undeclared(first use in this function) .(3)Request for member 'shadow' in something not a structure or union.

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? Shadow support was added between 0.4 and 0.9.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to update to 0.9 and use the property shown above.

Comment: I had updated to 0.9 now I'm not getting shadow to data label but now I'm getting two charts one on another, it seems like that I'm not getting what the problem is

Comment: +1 Thank you Eric! great work with Core Plot!!! wow! so easy to use even for a beginner as me! Thanks a million! :)